# Javascript - Nice way to convert 1/0 & 'true'/'false' & true/false to boolean

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that could sometimes be passed as 1/0 (both integer number or the string number), or it could be passed as a string 'true'/'false' or as an actual boolean true/false. I want to convert all of the cases to an actual boolean.

Other than doing a bunch of `if` statements and the `===` is there a faster and more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I think you need a special case for "false"

Comment: `!!eval(x)` does the trick - but I don't know how fast that would be...

Comment: @jlahd: or `!!JSON.parse(x)`, which is safer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy definitely a winner.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy nice one.. it should be answer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, I really like your answer. Why don't you type it as an answer and I'll select it?

Comment: @Kousha ikarous45 previously noted that it'd throw a SyntaxError if the string is invalid, which might make it not so useful. As well, if the string comes from an external source, you could hang the browser trying to parse a long string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an object with the mappings:

```
var translations = {
    "true": true,
    "1": true,
    "false": false,
    "0": false
};
```

And then

```
var my_value = "true";  # or 1, "false", 0... etc
var my_bool = translations[my_value];
```

In JS the keys of an object are automatically converted to string (by calling .toString if my memory does not fail), therefore `true` and `"true"` will return the same results. Same thing with `0` and `"0"`

**EDIT**

If your environment supports it, it would be even better to use a completely empty object:

```
var translations = Object.create(null);
translations['true'] = true;
...
```

Comment: +1 you are correct but there seems to be a function already exist in javascript. which I am not sure. still checking :)

Comment: Share it if you find it :)